# Only show replies realted to post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I'm looping to show each post and inside that loop looping to show all related replies. However currently all replies are showing up under every post on every board.

How can I only show the replies that are related to each post?

```
resources :boards, :path => '' do
    resources :posts, :path => 'thread' do
      resources :replies

class BoardsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @boards = Board.all
    @replies = Reply.all
  end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @board = Board.friendly.find(params[:board_id])
    @boards = Board.all
    @replies = Reply.all
    @post = Post.includes(:board).where('boards.slug' => params[:board_id]).friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :replies, through: :posts
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, :replies
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
  has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :replies
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :pid, :use => :scoped, :scope => :id
end
```

views/boards/show:

```
    <% @board.posts.find_each do |post| %>
    <%= post.subject %>
      <%= post.name %> 
      <%= post.email %> 
      <%= post.created_at %>
      No.<%= post.pid %>
    <%= link_to "[reply]", board_posts_path(@board, @post)%>
      <br>
      <%= post.comment %><br><br>
<% render "replies/replies" %>
    <% end %>
```

views/replies/_replies:

```
<% @replies.each do |reply| %>
    <p>
      >><%= reply.name %>
      <% reply.created_at %>
      <%= reply.email %> 
      <%= reply.subject %>
      <%= reply.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y(%a) %I:%M:%S ") %>
      No.<%= reply.pid %>
    <br>
      <%= reply.comment %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you paste your model code as well ?

Comment: @Shani updated the post

Comment: @aidiah ad your view code to question where you are showing posts and replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to set replies at controller level as replies belongs to posts. you can get all the replies for a given post by post.replies

in you view

```
@posts.each do |post|
  replies = post.replies // get all the replies that belongs to this post
  replies.each do |reply|
    reply.attribute
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to show only related replies in `_replies`, do not use generic `@replies`, use `post` there:

*views/boards/show*:

```
...
<% render "replies/replies", locals: {post: post} %>
```

*views/replies/_replies*:

```
<% post.replies.each do |reply| %>
  ...
```